# How to view Neural Network model internal architecture (embeds Module List) and (Layer) details in FastAi?

Tags: neural-network, categorical-data, tabular, embedding, fast-ai

I am trying to view the internal architecture of my trained neural network in FastAi. My model is trained using FastAi Tabular. How can I view the internal details of the model? I need to see the Embedding Module List for my categorical variables. I found the output from a Blog, but they didn't have the code for it. The output looks something like this:

```
TabularModel(
  (embeds): ModuleList(
    (0): Embedding(388505, 600)
    (1): Embedding(72, 18)
    (2): Embedding(331868, 600)
    (3): Embedding(5155, 192)
   ...
    (60): Embedding(3, 3)
    (61): Embedding(2, 2)
    (62): Embedding(3, 3)
  )
  (emb_drop): Dropout(p=0.04, inplace=False)
  (bn_cont): BatchNorm1d(2, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (layers): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=2102, out_features=1000, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): BatchNorm1d(1000, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (3): Dropout(p=0.001, inplace=False)
    (4): Linear(in_features=1000, out_features=500, bias=True)
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): BatchNorm1d(500, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (7): Dropout(p=0.01, inplace=False)
    (8): Linear(in_features=500, out_features=1, bias=True)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**It can simply be done using**

```
print(model)
```